# How to check whether a uint256 is null in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to check whether a `uint256` variable is null. How can I do so in solidity?

Comment: You can check it by comparing with 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any things like `null` in solidity.

All the uninitialized variables are set to a *zero like* value.

Have a look at [this answer for more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852682/are-there-null-like-thing-in-solidity).

Comment: Indeed, but I'd add that integers do not normally have nulls in any programming language. They are [primitives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_primitive).